# Redis database index restriction to IP

Tags: redis

in Redis, is it possible to only allow certain IP addresses can update selective database index?

For example:

```
127.0.0.1 can only update database index 1
127.0.0.2 can update all database indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [Per the docs](http://redis.io/topics/security):

> While Redis does not try to implement Access
>   Control, it provides a tiny layer of authentication that is optionally
>   turned on editing the redis.conf file. When the authorization layer is
>   enabled, Redis will refuse any query by unauthenticated clients. A
>   client can authenticate itself by sending the AUTH command followed by
>   the password.

A global password for authenticating is the only authentication Redis provides AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Eli for your inputs!

Comment: So if I want to set restriction to certain IP, I guess expose web services api to control permission is the way to go!